# Discord Bot - member is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

This is my code:

```js
bot.on('message', (message) => { //whenever a message is sent
    if (message.content.includes('discord.gg/'||'discordapp.com/invite/')) { //if it contains an invite link
      message.delete() //delete the message
        .then(message.channel.send(`**Hey <@${member.id}>! Don't Share Server Links.**`))
    }
  })
```

And I receive the following error:

```
.then(message.channel.send(`**Hey <@${member.id}>! Sunucu Linki Paylaşmamalısın.**`))
                                              ^

ReferenceError: member is not defined
    at Client.<anonymous> (C:\Users\ulaum\OneDrive\Masaüstü\Leet BOT\bot.js:18:47)
    at Client.emit (node:events:391:22)
    at MessageCreateAction.handle (C:\Users\ulaum\OneDrive\Masaüstü\Leet BOT\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\actions\MessageCreate.js:31:14)
    at Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE] (C:\Users\ulaum\OneDrive\Masaüstü\Leet BOT\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\handlers\MESSAGE_CREATE.js:4:32)
    at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (C:\Users\ulaum\OneDrive\Masaüstü\Leet BOT\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:384:31)
    at WebSocketShard.onPacket (C:\Users\ulaum\OneDrive\Masaüstü\Leet BOT\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:444:22)
    at WebSocketShard.onMessage (C:\Users\ulaum\OneDrive\Masaüstü\Leet BOT\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:301:10)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (C:\Users\ulaum\OneDrive\Masaüstü\Leet BOT\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:132:16)
    at WebSocket.emit (node:events:379:20)
    at Receiver.receiverOnMessage (C:\Users\ulaum\OneDrive\Masaüstü\Leet BOT\node_modules\ws\lib\websocket.js:825:20
```

Answer (score 2):

`member` is not defined as the error already mentioned. This means there is no variable called `member`. You could change your code into:

```js
bot.on('message', (message) => { //whenever a message is sent
    if (message.content.includes('discord.gg/'||'discordapp.com/invite/')) { //if it contains an invite link
      message.delete() //delete the message
        .then(message.channel.send(`**Hey <@${message.author.id}>! Don't Share Server Links.**`))
    }
  })
```

Comment: @omergencw Don't forget to mark this as accepted if Jannik's answer solved your problem. You can simply click the checkmark next to their answer.